# Rails-React app deployment fails on esbuild bundling because of inconsistent case-sensitiveness

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg, esbuild

I try to deploy a rails-react app and get an unexpected behaviour. When I try to deploy, deployment fails under certain conditions. I use Rails 7 with esbuild in combination with React. The deployment happens through Capistrano.

When I first tried to deploy the app from development to production I had yarn/node complain through capistrano about case-sensitive filenames. It worked in development, but did not precompile in production. After changing the filenames of the few components I had to small case, I was able to deploy. Now I have continued with my work and encountered a situation, where certain filenames need to be PascalCase and others follow a small case variant, such as snake_case. I do not know what is going on.

I get the following output:

```
00:11 deploy:assets:precompile
      01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm 3.2.1 do bundle exec rake assets:precompile
      01 yarn install v1.22.19
      01 [1/4] Resolving packages...
      01 [2/4] Fetching packages...
      01 [-----------------------------------] 0/35
      01 [3/4] Linking dependencies...
      01 [--------------] 0/14
      01 [-----------------------------------------------------------------------] 0/361
      01 [#################################################--------------------] 255/361
      01 [#####################################################################] 361/361
      01 [----------------------------] 0/28
      01 [4/4] Building fresh packages...
      01 [############################] 28/28
      01 [1/1] ⠂ esbuild
      01 Done in 0.44s.

      01 yarn run v1.22.19
      01 $ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets
      01 ▲ [WARNING] Use "app/javascript/components/resources.jsx" instead of "app/javascript/components/Resources.jsx" to avoid issues with case-sensitive file systems [different-path-case]
      01     app/javascript/routes/index.jsx:4:22:
      01       4 │ import Resources from "../components/Resources.jsx";
      01         ╵                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      01 ✘ [ERROR] Could not read from file: /home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/releases/20230304052541/app/javascript/components/Resources.jsx
      01     app/javascript/routes/index.jsx:4:22:
      01       4 │ import Resources from "../components/Resources.jsx";
      01         ╵                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      01 1 warning and 1 error
      01 node:child_process:924
      01     throw err;
      01     ^

      01 Error: Command failed: /home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/releases/20230304052541/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-x64/bin/esbuild app/javascript/application.js --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=ass…
      01     at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:885:11)
      01     at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:921:15)
      01     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/releases/20230304052541/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild:220:28)
      01     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
      01     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
      01     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
      01     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
      01     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
      01     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
      01   status: 1,
      01   signal: null,
      01   output: [ null, null, null ],
      01   pid: 3864772,
      01   stdout: null,
      01   stderr: null
      01 }

      01 Node.js v19.6.1
      01 error Command failed with exit code 1.
      01 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
      01 rake aborted!
      01 jsbundling-rails: Command build failed, ensure yarn is installed and `yarn build` runs without errors
      01 /home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jsbundling-rails-1.1.1/lib/tasks/jsbundling/build.rake:5:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
      01 /home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /home/amazing_account/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
      01 /home/amazing_account/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
      01 Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile => javascript:build
      01 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
      
#<Thread:0x000000011026c918 /Users/amazing_account/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@super_new_app/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
/Users/amazing_account/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@super_new_app/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing on host 92.205.63.233: rake exit status: 1 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
yarn install v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 0.44s.
yarn run v1.22.19
$ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets
▲ [WARNING] Use "app/javascript/components/resources.jsx" instead of "app/javascript/components/Resources.jsx" to avoid issues with case-sensitive file systems [different-path-case]

    app/javascript/routes/index.jsx:4:22:
      4 │ import Resources from "../components/Resources.jsx";
        ╵                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

✘ [ERROR] Could not read from file: /home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/releases/20230304052541/app/javascript/components/Resources.jsx

    app/javascript/routes/index.jsx:4:22:
      4 │ import Resources from "../components/Resources.jsx";
        ╵                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

1 warning and 1 error
node:child_process:924
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: /home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/releases/20230304052541/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-x64/bin/esbuild app/javascript/application.js --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets
    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:885:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:921:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/releases/20230304052541/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild:220:28)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 3864772,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}

Node.js v19.6.1
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
rake aborted!
jsbundling-rails: Command build failed, ensure yarn is installed and `yarn build` runs without errors
/home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jsbundling-rails-1.1.1/lib/tasks/jsbundling/build.rake:5:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/amazing_account/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/home/amazing_account/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile => javascript:build
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake stderr: Nothing written

    from /Users/amazing_account/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@super_new_app/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/Users/amazing_account/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@super_new_app/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/command.rb:97:in `exit_status=': rake exit status: 1 (SSHKit::Command::Failed)
yarn install v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 0.44s.
yarn run v1.22.19
$ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets
▲ [WARNING] Use "app/javascript/components/resources.jsx" instead of "app/javascript/components/Resources.jsx" to avoid issues with case-sensitive file systems [different-path-case]

    app/javascript/routes/index.jsx:4:22:
      4 │ import Resources from "../components/Resources.jsx";
        ╵                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

✘ [ERROR] Could not read from file: /home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/releases/20230304052541/app/javascript/components/Resources.jsx

    app/javascript/routes/index.jsx:4:22:
      4 │ import Resources from "../components/Resources.jsx";
        ╵                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

1 warning and 1 error
node:child_process:924
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: /home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/releases/20230304052541/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-x64/bin/esbuild app/javascript/application.js --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets
    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:885:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:921:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/releases/20230304052541/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild:220:28)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 3864772,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}

Node.js v19.6.1
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
rake aborted!
jsbundling-rails: Command build failed, ensure yarn is installed and `yarn build` runs without errors
/home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jsbundling-rails-1.1.1/lib/tasks/jsbundling/build.rake:5:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/amazing_account/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/home/amazing_account/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile => javascript:build
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake stderr: Nothing written

    from /Users/amazing_account/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@super_new_app/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:170:in `execute_command'
    from /Users/amazing_account/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@super_new_app/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
    from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    from /Users/amazing_account/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@super_new_app/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `create_command_and_execute'
    from /Users/amazing_account/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@super_new_app/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:80:in `execute'
    from /Users/amazing_account/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@super_new_app/gems/capistrano-rails-1.6.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:69:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/amazing_account/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@super_new_app/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:100:in `with'
    from /Users/amazing_account/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@super_new_app/gems/capistrano-rails-1.6.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:68:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/amazing_account/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@super_new_app/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:92:in `within'
    from /Users/amazing_account/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@super_new_app/gems/capistrano-rails-1.6.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:67:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/amazing_account/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@super_new_app/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/amazing_account/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@super_new_app/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `run'
    from /Users/amazing_account/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@super_new_app/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host 92.205.63.233: rake exit status: 1
yarn install v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 0.44s.
yarn run v1.22.19
$ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets
▲ [WARNING] Use "app/javascript/components/resources.jsx" instead of "app/javascript/components/Resources.jsx" to avoid issues with case-sensitive file systems [different-path-case]

    app/javascript/routes/index.jsx:4:22:
      4 │ import Resources from "../components/Resources.jsx";
        ╵                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

✘ [ERROR] Could not read from file: /home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/releases/20230304052541/app/javascript/components/Resources.jsx

    app/javascript/routes/index.jsx:4:22:
      4 │ import Resources from "../components/Resources.jsx";
        ╵                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

1 warning and 1 error
node:child_process:924
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: /home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/releases/20230304052541/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-x64/bin/esbuild app/javascript/application.js --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets
    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:885:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:921:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/releases/20230304052541/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild:220:28)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 3864772,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}

Node.js v19.6.1
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
rake aborted!
jsbundling-rails: Command build failed, ensure yarn is installed and `yarn build` runs without errors
/home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jsbundling-rails-1.1.1/lib/tasks/jsbundling/build.rake:5:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/amazing_account/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/home/amazing_account/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile => javascript:build
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake stderr: Nothing written


Caused by:
SSHKit::Command::Failed: rake exit status: 1
yarn install v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 0.44s.
yarn run v1.22.19
$ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets
▲ [WARNING] Use "app/javascript/components/resources.jsx" instead of "app/javascript/components/Resources.jsx" to avoid issues with case-sensitive file systems [different-path-case]

    app/javascript/routes/index.jsx:4:22:
      4 │ import Resources from "../components/Resources.jsx";
        ╵                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

✘ [ERROR] Could not read from file: /home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/releases/20230304052541/app/javascript/components/Resources.jsx

    app/javascript/routes/index.jsx:4:22:
      4 │ import Resources from "../components/Resources.jsx";
        ╵                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

1 warning and 1 error
node:child_process:924
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: /home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/releases/20230304052541/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-x64/bin/esbuild app/javascript/application.js --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets
    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:885:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:921:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/releases/20230304052541/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild:220:28)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 3864772,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}

Node.js v19.6.1
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
rake aborted!
jsbundling-rails: Command build failed, ensure yarn is installed and `yarn build` runs without errors
/home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jsbundling-rails-1.1.1/lib/tasks/jsbundling/build.rake:5:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/amazing_account/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/home/amazing_account/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile => javascript:build
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing on host 92.205.63.233: rake exit status: 1
yarn install v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 0.44s.
yarn run v1.22.19
$ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets
▲ [WARNING] Use "app/javascript/components/resources.jsx" instead of "app/javascript/components/Resources.jsx" to avoid issues with case-sensitive file systems [different-path-case]

    app/javascript/routes/index.jsx:4:22:
      4 │ import Resources from "../components/Resources.jsx";
        ╵                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

✘ [ERROR] Could not read from file: /home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/releases/20230304052541/app/javascript/components/Resources.jsx

    app/javascript/routes/index.jsx:4:22:
      4 │ import Resources from "../components/Resources.jsx";
        ╵                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

1 warning and 1 error
node:child_process:924
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: /home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/releases/20230304052541/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-x64/bin/esbuild app/javascript/application.js --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets
    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:885:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:921:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/releases/20230304052541/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild:220:28)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 3864772,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}

Node.js v19.6.1
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
rake aborted!
jsbundling-rails: Command build failed, ensure yarn is installed and `yarn build` runs without errors
/home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jsbundling-rails-1.1.1/lib/tasks/jsbundling/build.rake:5:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/amazing_account/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/home/amazing_account/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile => javascript:build
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake stderr: Nothing written


** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:




 DEBUG [a5459457]   

 DEBUG [a5459457]   info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

 DEBUG [a5459457]   

 DEBUG [a5459457]   rake aborted!

 DEBUG [a5459457]   

 DEBUG [a5459457]   jsbundling-rails: Command build failed, ensure yarn is installed and `yarn build` runs without errors

 DEBUG [a5459457]   

 DEBUG [a5459457]   /home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jsbundling-rails-1.1.1/lib/tasks/jsbundling/build.rake:5:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'

 DEBUG [a5459457]   

 DEBUG [a5459457]   /home/amazing_account/apps/super_new_app/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'

 DEBUG [a5459457]   

 DEBUG [a5459457]   /home/amazing_account/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'

 DEBUG [a5459457]   

 DEBUG [a5459457]   /home/amazing_account/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'

 DEBUG [a5459457]   

 DEBUG [a5459457]   Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile => javascript:build

 DEBUG [a5459457]   

 DEBUG [a5459457]   (See full trace by running task with --trace)

 DEBUG [a5459457]
```

At the current moment I have this situation:

[image]

I had to rename App.jsx to app.jsx, Resources.jsx to resources.jsx, but had to keep Topic.jsx titleized.

The esbuild script, that runs is defined in the package.json as follows:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": "true",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "^3.2.1",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "^7.2.5",
    "esbuild": "^0.17.8",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets"
  }
}
```

I tried to clean up by changing all component names to PascalCase following the react convention. I also changed the import statements in them accordingly, but the deployment fails with the error message above. I had to revert back to the a mixed setting and would like to solve this.